# django login_required decorator ViewDoesNotExist

Tags: django, login-required

I'm using `@login_required(login_url=settings.LOGIN_URL)` and getting `ViewDoesNotExist` exception.

Odd things are:

- the views referenced in the exception message are not being programmatically referenced by my code
- the views referenced in the exception used to exist but no longer do, and they are not being pointed to in urls.py
- the problem goes away when I remove @`login_required`

I have tried deleting urs.py thinging maybe problems with cached pyc files, but nope.

It seems that django is somehow remembering the old views?

Comment: Might be your `settings.LOGIN_URL` url is wrong, when it tries to redirect you to login page it says `ViewDoesNotExist`.

Answer (score -1):

occurs becasue moved urls.py to wrong place. resolved by moving it back.